# How does implements Comparator work in java?

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

[Java Comparator interface](https://www.javatpoint.com/Comparator-interface-in-collection-framework) - 
Here is an example of how `Comparator` works.

**My question is :**  Where is `Object` type `o1` and `o2` coming when the method `compare(Object o1,Object o2)` ? I don't know see any `Class` invoke the compare() method. I only see Collections.sort(al,new NameComparator());

Please explain, thank you.

Comment: The `sort` routine will call compare on objects in the list a few times until the list is sorted

Answer (score 1):

When you call Collections.sort on any collection and pass the comparator reference , The underlying sorting method makes a call to compare method to decide which one is greater between two objects. This process happens according to the sorting strategy.

Java code reference: Here is the chaining:

1. You call Collections.sort(collectionReference, comparatorReference)
2. the first one internally calls:   list.sort(comparatorReference);
3. list.sort internally converts the list to array and call
       `Object[] a = this.toArray();
       Arrays.sort(a, (Comparator) comparatorReference);`
4. Arrays.sort has the following logic:

   ```
    public static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c) {
      if (c == null) {
       sort(a);
      } else {
        if (LegacyMergeSort.userRequested)
           legacyMergeSort(a, c);
        else
           TimSort.sort(a, 0, a.length, c, null, 0, 0);
      }
    }
   ```
5. Let's inspect one of the sorting technique if c is not null:legacyMergeSort.

One Snippet which calls compare method:

```
   if (length < INSERTIONSORT_THRESHOLD) {
    for (int i=low; i<high; i++)
        for (int j=i; j>low && c.compare(dest[j-1], dest[j])>0; j--)
            swap(dest, j, j-1);
    return;
  }
```

notice the c.compare method.

It's not good if I post the entire class code here. Please look the classes that i listed and you will find references of where the call to compare method exist which makes comparator logic works in collection sorting.